# How do I parse YAML with nil values?

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, yaml

I apologize for the very specific issue I'm posting here but I hope it will help others that may also run across this issue.  I have a string that is being formatted to the following:

```
[[,action1,,],[action2],[]]
```

I would like to translate this to valid YAML so that it can be parsed which would look like this:

```
[['','acton1','',''],['action2'],['']]
```

I've tried a bunch of regular expressions to accomplish this but I'm afraid that I'm at a complete loss.  I'm ok with running multiple expressions if needed. For example (ruby):

```
puts s.gsub!(/,/,"','")  # => [[','action1','',']','[action2]','[]]
puts s.gsub!(/\[',/, "['',") # => [['','action1','',']','[action2]','[]]
```

That's getting there, but I have a feeling I'm starting to go down a rat-hole with this approach. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the job for the empty fields (ruby1.9):

```
s.gsub(/(?<=[\[,])(?=[,\]])/, "''")
```

Or for ruby1.8, which doesn't support zero-width look-behind:

```
s.gsub(/([\[,])(?=[,\]])/, "\\1''")
```

Quoting non-empty fields can be done with one of these:

```
s.gsub(/(?<=[\[,])\b|\b(?=[,\]])/, "'")
s.gsub(/(\w+)/, "'\\1'")
```

In the above I'm making use of zero-width positive look behind and zero-width positive look ahead assertions (the '(?<=' and '(?=').

I've looked for some ruby specific documentation but could not find anything that explains these features in particular. Instead, please let me refer you to [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions).

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work. I'm not sure if ruby supports the look behind or look ahead syntax you used. I get the following error: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=[\\[,])(?=[,\\]])/

Comment: Ah, I've used ruby1.9. Earlier versions may not support these features.

Comment: No, lookbehinds aren't supported out-of-the-box before 1.9.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for elaborating. I am using 1.8 so the additional code for both versions is greatly appreciated.  You are a wiz!

Answer (score 3):

#### It would be easier to just parse it, then output valid YAML.

---

Since I don't know Ruby, Here is an example in Perl.

---

Since you only want a subset of YAML, that appears to be similar to JSON, I used the [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/JSON) module.

I've been wanting an excuse to use [`Regexp::Grammars`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp::Grammars), so I used it to parse the data.

I guarantee it will work, no matter how deep the arrays are.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
#use warnings;
use 5.010;
#use YAML;
use JSON;
use Regexp::Grammars;


my $str = '[[,action1,,],[action2],[],[,],[,[],]]';

my $parser = qr{
  <match=Array>

  <token: Text>
    [^,\[\]]*

  <token: Element>
  (?:
    <.Text>
  |
    <MATCH=Array>
  )

  <token: Array>
  \[
     (?:
       (?{ $MATCH = [qw'']; })
     |
       <[MATCH=Element]>   ** (,)
     )
  \]
}x;


if( $str =~ $parser ){
  say to_json $/{match};
}else{
  die $@ if $@;
}
```

Which outputs.

```
[["","action1","",""],["action2"],[],["",""],["",[],""]]
```

If you really wanted YAML, just un comment "`use YAML;`", and replace `to_json()` with `Dump()`

```
---
-
  - ''
  - action1
  - ''
  - ''
-
  - action2
- []
-
  - ''
  - ''
-
  - ''
  - []
  - ''
```

Comment: +1 That's a very nice demonstration. The regexp way works for deep lists too though.

Comment: I always find it harder to figure out if a regex/replace will work, than just parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s.gsub(/([\[,])(?=[,\]])/, "\\1''")
 .gsub(/([\[,])(?=[^'\[])|([^\]'])(?=[,\]])/, "\\+'");
```

EDIT: I'm not sure about the replacement syntax.  That's supposed to be group #1 in the first `gsub`, and the highest-numbered participating group -- `$+` -- in the second.

Comment: You have to use "\\1''", or '\1\'\'' to refer to capturing groups.